# Inheritance and class scope in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm try learn about inheritance in PHP. A question that I can't get it.
I have a block code like following:

```
class BaseClass {
    private $name = "BaseClass";
    public function getName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private $name = "ChildClass";
}

$ob = new ChildClass;
echo $ob->getName(); //result: "BaseClass" . I think its result is "ChildClass".
```

However, when change visibility of **$name** to **public** so result is difference.

```
class BaseClass {
    public $name = "BaseClass";
    public function getName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public $name = "ChildClass";
}

$ob = new ChildClass;
echo $ob->getName(); // Result: "ChildClass".
```

Please help me explain this problem. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the reason for this is that private properties are not overwritten. Instead two properties are formed. If you change `private` to `protected`, it will work.

When you call the `getName()` method, your scope will be that of the parent, because it does not exist in the child. In your example, `private $name` exists twice. And because of scope, you'll get the value of the parent property (`$this` will try to call private methods from the same scope).

If you do `var_dump($ob)`, you'll see what I mean:

```
object(ChildClass)#1 (2) {
  ["name":"BaseClass":private]=>
  string(9) "BaseClass"
  ["name":"ChildClass":private]=>
  string(10) "ChildClass"
}
```

If you overwrite the parent method in the child class, the result will also work, as you change the scope.

Hope that helps.